# How to create methods that run firstly before going to other methods in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm creating CRUD app with vuejs and axios for ajax. i also make a login before doing CRUD, but i want validate a user before doing CRUD in this case i'm using vuejs only for rendering data to html from ajax

i make an insert method for inserting data to database, and check_login method that return result of isLogin from ajax. In the first line of insert method i include it for validating user is login or not. but the problem is i create more than 3 CRUD in my app so i think this way is not simple because i always have to create variable that gets returning value from check_login method. is there any solution for my case?

```
 methods:{

  check_login(){
    axios.get(this.url+'login/check').then(function(response){
    vue.login_result = response.data.status;    
    })
    return this.login_result;
  }, 

  insert(){
  let login_result = this.check_login();
  if (!login_result) {
  alert('you are not login');
  }else{
  //ajax insert here
  }

  },

  }
```

i want before doing insert method, the check_login method runs automatically, maybe it's like function __construct in php.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can add a mounted () instance like this.

```
mounted (){
   this.check_login()
},

methods:{
    check_login(){
        axios.get(this.url+'login/check').then(function(response){
            vue.login_result = response.data.status;    
        })
            return this.login_result;
    }, 

    insert(){
        let login_result = this.check_login();
        if (!login_result) {
            alert('you are not login');
        }else{
            //ajax insert here
        }
    },
}
```

The page run the check_login method first when page loaded

Answer (score 0):

Why not utilize the ES6 async await?
Something similar to this

```
 methods:{
  async check_login(){
   return  axios.get(this.url+'login/check').then((response)=>
    response.data.status;    
    )
  }, 

  async insert(){
    let login_result = await this.check_login();
    if (!login_result) {
      alert('you are not login');
    }else{
      //ajax insert here
     }

  },

}
```

You can after all declare async functions in vue methods.

Comment: what want is remove login_result variable, so before execute insert method, the check login is always executed

Comment: You can try mounted hook but It really depends on what will you do if its not logged in.